# In XAMPP where can I find "storage/myisam/ftdefs.h" for mysql?

Tags: mysql, xampp, myisam

I am looking for the `"storage/myisam/"` directory to access the `"ftdefs.h"` file. I am using XAMPP (v3.2.1) for my mysql services. So far, I can't seem to find the file. Is it even possible to access it via XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that `ftdefs.h` doesn't exist because XAMPP doesn't give the MySQL source code. It is already compiled.

You'll have to download MySQL separately and then you'll be able to find `ftdefs.h`.